# Can Hadoop MapReduce can run over other filesystems?

Tags: hadoop

I heard like for mapreduce jobs input need not in HDFS. It can be on other file system.. Can someone please provide me more inputs on this..

I am litle confused on this? In standalone mode, data can be on local file system. But in cluster mode how can we point to mapreduce jobs to some other file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not need to be in HDFS. For instance jobs which target HBase using its TableInputFormat pull records over the network from HBase nodes as inputs to its map jobs. The DbInputFormat can be used to pull data from a SQL database into a job. You could build an input format that did something like read data off of an NFS mount.

In practice you want to avoid pulling data over the network if you can. MR performance is much better if you can have your data locally on the nodes where the job is being  run since Disk Throughput > Network Throughput.

Answer (score 2):

Based in the InputFormat set on the job, Hadoop can read from any source. Hadoop provides a couple of [InputFormats](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html). It's not difficult to write a [custom](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat) InputFormat also, let's say to provide a proprietary format as input to a Job.

On the same lines Hadoop provides a couple of [OutputFormats](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/OutputFormat.html) and it shouldn't be difficult to write a custom OutputFormat also.

Here is a nice [article](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/) on the DBInputFormat.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the input. My question is, is it possible to give input/output path as local file system path, while running hadoop mapreduce jobs in the cluster. i.e is mapreduce jobs can take input from the local file system instaed of HDFS. If so, could you please give me simple example?

Comment: I don't think so. Is there any use case around this? What happens to the data if the node with your `local data` goes down?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it is to put into HDFS files with information where the real data is. Mapper will get this information and pull real data for the processing.
For example we can have several files with URLs of data to be processed.
What we will loose in this case is data locality - otherwise it is fine.